# SwiftUI semicircular interactive progress bar

Tags: swiftui

Hi I am trying to develop a semi circular interactive progress bar using swift UI but am not able to get the expected output I am trying to achieve something similar to this

[image]

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
struct SemiCircularProgressBar: View {
    @State var progressValue: Float = 0.0
    @State private var degrees: Double = -90
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ProgressBar(progress: self.$progressValue)
                    .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
                    .padding(40.0)
                
                ProgressThumb(progress: self.$progressValue)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .offset(x: self.thumbOffset().x, y: self.thumbOffset().y)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                let angle = self.angle(for: gesture.location)
                                self.updateProgress(for: angle)
                            }
                    )
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func angle(for location: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let vector = CGVector(dx: location.x, dy: location.y)
        let angle = atan2(vector.dy, vector.dx)
        return Double(angle * 180 / .pi)
    }
    
    private func updateProgress(for angle: Double) {
        let totalAngle: Double = 220
        let minAngle: Double = -110
        let maxAngle: Double = minAngle + totalAngle
        var normalizedAngle = min(max(minAngle, angle), maxAngle)
        if normalizedAngle > 88.8 {
            normalizedAngle = 88.8
        }
        let progress = Float((normalizedAngle - minAngle) / totalAngle)
        self.progressValue = progress
        self.degrees = normalizedAngle
    }
    
    private func thumbOffset() -> CGPoint {
        let thumbRadius: CGFloat = 125 // half of progress bar diameter
        let radians = CGFloat(degrees) * .pi / -100
        let x = thumbRadius * cos(radians)
        let y = thumbRadius * sin(radians)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Float
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.3, to: 0.9)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.3, to: CGFloat(self.progress))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "ED4D4D"), location: 0.39000002),
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "E59148"), location: 0.48000002),
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "EFBF39"), location: 0.5999999),
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "EEED56"), location: 0.7199998),
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "32E1A0"), location: 0.8099997)]), center: .center))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
            
            VStack {
                Text("824").font(Font.system(size: 44)).bold().foregroundColor(Color(hex: "314058"))
                Text("Great Score!").bold().foregroundColor(Color(hex: "32E1A0"))
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ProgressThumb: View {
    @Binding var progress: Float
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
}

extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        }
        
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(r) / 255,
            green: Double(g) / 255,
            blue:  Double(b) / 255,
            opacity: Double(a) / 255
        )
    }
}


#Preview {
    SemiCircularProgressBar()
}
```

Using this above code I am able to achieve something like this
[image]

The problems which I face here is like the thumb should be smooth and able to drag with in the semi circle. I am expecting a semicircle with a knob to show the progress. Thanks in advance

Comment: By 'thumb' do you mean the bit at the end of the fill?  And are you expecting to be able to drag it with a touch gesture, or do you just mean get a smooth animation as the value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to drag the blue button along the arc of the progress bar and the progress should be filled with color to correspond to the button position.

I don't quite understand why it would make sense to be able to adjust the progress manually like this, but anyway, if this is the right understanding then the following changes can be used to get it working:

- Use the limits consistently. The function `updateProgress` was using min/max limits of -110 degrees to +110 degrees, but then it was capping the result at 88.8 degrees for some reason. Also, the progress arc was being drawn from 0.3 to 0.9, which would represent an angle of 216 degrees. I've stuck with -110 degrees to +110 degrees (= 220 degrees total) and adapted the other limits accordingly.
- If the blue button is positioned at 12 o' clock when the angle is 0, then the computed progress angle can simply be applied as a rotation effect, instead of adjusting x and y offsets. To position the button at 12 o' clock, all it takes is a negative y-offset equal to the radius.
- Likewise, it is much simpler if the progress bar starts at 0 and then a rotation effect is used to change the start position to -110 degrees, instead of trimming from 0.3 to 0.9 and applying a rotation effect of 54.5 degrees (which should have actually been 54 degrees).
- I would suggest using `Double` for `progressValue` as it simplifies some of the computation.
- The function `angle` needs to take the size of the button into consideration.
- To make the animation more responsive to small drag movements, supply a `minimumDistance` to the  `DragGesture`, for example, `minimumDistance: 1`.
- The progress bar does not need to be passed a binding to the progress level, because it is read-only. It can be a `let` property instead.
- The button does not need to be passed the progress level at all.
- Large movements can be smoothed by adding an `.animation` modifier to the `ZStack`.

Here you go, hope it helps:

```swift
struct SemiCircularProgressBar: View {
    @State private var progressValue: Double = 0.0
    @State private var degrees: Double = -110

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ProgressBar(progress: progressValue) // self.$progressValue
                    .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
                    .padding(40.0)

                ProgressThumb() // self.$progressValue
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .offset(y: -125) // circle radius
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(degrees))
//                    .offset(x: self.thumbOffset().x, y: self.thumbOffset().y)
//                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1)
                            .onChanged { gesture in
//                                let angle = self.angle(for: gesture.location)
                                let angle = location2Degrees(location: gesture.location)
                                updateProgress(for: angle)
                            }
                    )
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15), value: degrees)
            Spacer()
        }
    }

//    private func angle(for location: CGPoint) -> Double {
//        let vector = CGVector(dx: location.x, dy: location.y)
//        let angle = atan2(vector.dy, vector.dx)
//        return Double(angle * 180 / .pi)
//    }

    private func location2Degrees(location: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let halfButtonSize = 30.0 / 2
        let radians = atan2(location.x - halfButtonSize, halfButtonSize - location.y)
        let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
        return degrees < -180
            ? degrees + 360
            : degrees > 180 ? degrees - 360 : degrees
    }

    private func updateProgress(for angle: Double) {
        let totalAngle: Double = 220
        let minAngle: Double = -110
        let maxAngle: Double = minAngle + totalAngle
        let normalizedAngle = min(max(minAngle, angle), maxAngle)
//        if normalizedAngle > 88.8 {
//            normalizedAngle = 88.8
//        }
        self.progressValue = (normalizedAngle - minAngle) / totalAngle
        self.degrees = normalizedAngle
    }

//    private func thumbOffset() -> CGPoint {
//        let thumbRadius: CGFloat = 125 // half of progress bar diameter
//        let radians = CGFloat(degrees) * .pi / -100
//        let x = thumbRadius * cos(radians)
//        let y = thumbRadius * sin(radians)
//        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
//    }
}

struct ProgressBar: View {
    let progress: Double // @Binding var progress: Float
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 220.0 / 360) // (from: 0.3, to: 0.9)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90 - 110)) // .degrees(54.5)

            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: (progress * 220.0) / 360) // (from: 0.3, to: CGFloat(self.progress))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "ED4D4D"), location: 0), // 0.39000002
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "E59148"), location: 65.0 / 260), // 0.48000002
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "EFBF39"), location: 110.0 / 360), // 0.5999999
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "EEED56"), location: 175.0 / 360), // 0.7199998
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "32E1A0"), location: 220.0 / 360), // 0.8099997
                    .init(color: Color(hex: "ED4D4D"), location: 1) 
                ]),center: .center))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90 - 110)) // .degrees(54.5)

            VStack {
                Text("824").font(Font.system(size: 44)).bold().foregroundColor(Color(hex: "314058"))
                Text("Great Score!").bold().foregroundColor(Color(hex: "32E1A0"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressThumb: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]